# Changing namespace on my controller - Silex framework

Tags: php, silex

I'll go straight to the point, I only changed the controller namespace Musique\Controller to STM\Controller

```
 namespace STM\Controller;

use Silex\Application;

class HomeController{

public function indexAction(Application $app){
    return $app['twig']->render("index.html.twig");
}
```

also changed my composer.json file

```
{
"name": "jasonazoulay/SoTrustMe",
"description": "Tiers de confiance",
"authors": [
    {
        "name": "Jason Azoulay",

    }
],
"require": {
    "silex/silex": "^2.0",
    "doctrine/dbal": "~2.5",
    "twig/twig": "^1.33",
    "symfony/asset": "^3.2",
    "symfony/twig-bridge": "^3.2",
    "symfony/form": "~2.8|3.0.*",
    "symfony/translation": "~2.8|3.0.*",
    "symfony/config": "~2.8|3.0.*"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {"SoTrustMe\\": "src"}
}
```

}
and of course the route also

```
$app->get('/',"STM\Controller\HomeController::indexAction")->bind('home');
```

and now i get this error

InvalidArgumentException in ControllerResolver.php line 187:
Class "STM\Controller\HomeController" does not exist.

though it was working just fine before I change the namespace !

please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are loading your classes with composer and you introduced a new directory in your project you are going to need to re-run: `composer dump-autoload`

this will regenerate the list of all classes that need to be included in the project and updates the Composer cache. For more detail regarding this issue you could have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33973967/why-do-i-have-to-run-composer-dump-autoload-command-to-make-migration-work-in) question.

Comment: Thank you very much maybe this works, but my issue was this part
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {"SoTrustMe\\": "src"}
}
I just had to put the root namespace .. so STM and then run composer update
generates new autoloader  for this namespace and solved my issue !