# Laravel 5.5 socialite integration shows error formatRedirectUrl() must be of the type array, null given

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-socialite

I am using "laravel/socialite": "^3.0", to facebook login. But it shows
an error

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteManager::formatRedirectUrl() must be of the type array, null given, called in /var/www/html/mas/vendor/laravel/socialite/src/SocialiteManager.php.

It happens when I am calling the below function in my login controller

```
public function socialLogin($social)
{
    return Socialite::driver($social)->redirect();
}
```

Answer (score 23):

Hi you are missing to give credentials of social media put that in config/services.php

```
'facebook' => [
        'client_id' => env('FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID'),
        'client_secret' => env('FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET'),
        'redirect' => env('CALLBACK_URL_FACEBOOK'),
    ],
    'google' => [
        'client_id' => env('GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'),
        'client_secret' => env('GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET'),
        'redirect' => env('CALLBACK_URL_GOOGLE'),
    ],
    'twitter' => [
        'client_id' => env('TWITTER_CLIENT_ID'),
        'client_secret' => env('TWITTER_CLIENT_SECRET'),
        'redirect' => env('CALLBACK_URL_TWITTER'),
    ],
    'linkedin' => [
        'client_id' => env('LINKEDIN_CLIENT_ID'),
        'client_secret' => env('LINKEDIN_CLIENT_SECRET'),
        'redirect' => env('CALLBACK_URL_LINKEDIN'),
    ],
    'instagram' => [
        'client_id' => env('INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_ID'),
        'client_secret' => env('INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_SECRET'),
        'redirect' => env('CALLBACK_URL_INSTAGRAM'),
    ],
```

Comment: I have that in my config/services.php. But It cann't read from vendor/laravel/socialite/src/SocialiteManager.php . I can access all other arrays in services.php, except facebook credentials. I don't know Why.

Comment: thanks, man I have missed these credential on the live server  in config/services.php files now every thing is fine

Answer (score 19):

You must clear the configuration cache file, how? if you use `php artisan` you will see the command config:clear. Run it:

```
php artisan config:clear
```

and now if you access to the $config variable inside the Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteManager::createFacebookDriver()
you will get the configuration element stored in config/services.facebook (Facebook, for example) that before was not 'visible' for Socialite.

**In short**: run `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: There are no commands defined in the "config" namespace. in lumen

Comment: What are the solution for lumen?

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me just recently, fixed it after reading the following post here on StackOverflow:

[Why do I have to run "composer dump-autoload" command to make migration work in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33973967/why-do-i-have-to-run-composer-dump-autoload-command-to-make-migration-work-in)

The solution is basically to run the following commands:

`php artisan clear-compiled 
composer dump-autoload
php artisan optimize`

Comment: do this and believe me, it solves the problem. thanks

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the parameters passed to the function socialLogin($social).
Try by manually setting the 'github' or 'facebook' string in the drvier function of Socialite.

Dont forget to mention 'github' , 'facebook, etc in the route in web.php

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem.

I got this errot because of copy/paste while reading Laravel doc. In my case in loginController.php changed this:

```
// I copied this from Laravel doc
public function redirectToProvider()
{
    return Socialite::driver('github')->redirect();
}

//What I really needed
public function redirectToProvider()
{
    return Socialite::driver('google')->redirect();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue even after had set up my `config/services.php` file and managed to solve it by clearing my cache. In your project directory run

```
php artisan optimize:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

This ensures that your entire cache is cleared.

**NOTE**: changing core files in Laravel most of the times require you running the above commands as Laravel tends to use caching to a greater extend to improve on application speeds

Answer (score 0):

Try these

1. Check if you have all your social media in config/services.php
2. On your register or login page check the url that corresponds to facebook

   `a href="{{ url('/login/facebook') }}"`
3. Go to Routes and check if you have routes properly configured

   `Route::get('login/{social}', 'Auth\LoginController@redirectToProvider');
   Route::get('login/{social}/callback', 'Auth\LoginController@handleProviderCallback');`
4. Open Auth/LoginController and check if have

   `use Socialite;
   public function redirectToProvider($social)
   {
     Socialite::driver($social)->redirect();
   }
   public function handleProviderCallback($social)
   {
    $user = Socialite::driver($social)->user();
   }`

As you've mentioned you are only facing the error with facebook, im pretty sure it must be in first three steps

Answer (score 0):

Open vendor\laravel\socialite\src\SocialiteManager.php
Replace to 
protected function formatRedirectUrl(array $config)
    {
        $redirect = value($config['redirect']);

```
    return Str::startsWith($redirect, '/')
                ? $this->app['url']->to($redirect)
                : $redirect;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Open vendor\laravel\socialite\src\SocialiteManager.php and 
Replace
  protected function createFacebookDriver()
    {
         $config = $this->app['config']['services.facebook'];
          return $this->buildProvider(
            FacebookProvider::class, $config
        );
    }

To
  protected function createFacebookDriver()
    {
         $config = $this->app['config']['services.stripe.facebook'];
          return $this->buildProvider(
            FacebookProvider::class, $config
        );
    }
```