# OAuth error "Trying to access array offset on value of type null" using Socialite

Tags: laravel, laravel-socialite

I making OAuth using Laravel Socialite, step by step i trying 3 different guides and result the same error `Trying to access array offset on value of type null`.

My composer.json

```
"require": {
        "php": "^7.3.1",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "laravel/framework": "^6.2",
        "laravel/socialite": "^4.3",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
        "laravel/ui": "^1.2",
        "socialiteproviders/vkontakte": "^4.0"
    },
```

Also my LoginController

```
public function redirectToProvider()
    {
        return Socialite::driver('github')->redirect();
    }

    public function handleProviderCallback()
    {
        $user = Socialite::driver('github')->user();

        dd($user);
    }
```

Comment: Could you post the full stack trace?

Comment: https://imgur.com/gcgNz67.png

Comment: I had the same problem. This thread helped me to solve it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47365532/laravel-5-5-socialite-integration-shows-error-formatredirecturl-must-be-of-the

Answer (score 13):

if you entered your `client_id` and `secret_id` **config/services.php** then run `php artisan config:clear`

Answer (score 4):

probably you forgot to add services to you services.php
so go to config/services and add

```
'github' => [
        'client_id' => env('GITHUB_CLIENT_ID'),
        'client_secret' => env('GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET'),
        'redirect' => env('GITHUB_REDIRECT'),
    ],
 'google' => [
        'client_id' => env('GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'),
        'client_secret' => env('GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET'),
        'redirect' => env('GOOGLE_REDIRECT'),
    ]
```

after that go to env and add to your providers  keys  and values

Comment: This was it for me.

Answer (score -2):

I had faced the same issue and I finally came to a solution. The problem is probably due to the depreciation of app['request'] in *SocialiteManager.php* file located in *Vendor/Laravel/Socialite/src/SocialiteManager.php*.

The solution to this problem is by following the following steps:

> **Step 1:** Go to *Vendor/Laravel/Socialite/src/SocialiteManager.php*.
> **Step 2:** Copy and paste the following code in buildProvider method.
>
> ```
> public function buildProvider($provider, $config)
>     {
>         return new $provider(
>             $this->container->make('request'),
>             $config['client_id'],
>             $config['client_secret'],
>             $this->formatRedirectUrl($config),
>             Arr::get($config, 'guzzle', [])
>         );
>     }
> ```
>
> **Step 3:** Run *php artisan config:cache* and *php artisan cache:clear* to clear the previous cache then run the app. Hola!
> You're done!

Comment: No need to add this. My files are already same with this code