# Composer can't find file on Linux

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

when I try

```
    composer dump-autoload
```

I get the following error on my linux machine

```
            > Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
    PHP Warning:  Uncaught ErrorException: require(/App/Helpers/AppHelper.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/page/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php:66
    Stack trace:
    #0 /var/www/page/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php(66): Composer\Util\ErrorHandler::handle(2, 'require(/App/He...', '/var/www/pag...', 66, Array)
    #1 /var/www/page/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php(66): require()
    #2 /var/www/page/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php(56): composerRequire14063f7e5e06d46e1f9f9d444238e903('ba1c657daf90253...', '/App/Helpers/Ap...')
    #3 /var/www/page/vendor/autoload.php(7): ComposerAutoloaderInit14063f7e5e06d46e1f9f9d444238e903::getLoader()
    #4 /var/www/page/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ComposerScripts.php(43): require_once('/var/www/pag...')
    #5 phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(292): Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump(Object(Composer\Script\Event))
    #6 phar:///usr/local/bin/com in /var/www/page/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66

    Warning: Uncaught ErrorException: require(/App/Helpers/AppHelper.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/page/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php:66
    Stack trace:
    #0 /var/www/page/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php(66): Composer\Util\ErrorHandler::handle(2, 'require(/App/He...', '/var/www/pag...', 66, Array)
    #1 /var/www/page/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php(66): require()
    #2 /var/www/page/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php(56): composerRequire14063f7e5e06d46e1f9f9d444238e903('ba1c657daf90253...', '/App/Helpers/Ap...')
    #3 /var/www/page/vendor/autoload.php(7): ComposerAutoloaderInit14063f7e5e06d46e1f9f9d444238e903::getLoader()
    #4 /var/www/page/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ComposerScripts.php(43): require_once('/var/www/pag...')
    #5 phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(292): Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump(Object(Composer\Script\Event))
    #6 phar:///usr/local/bin/com in /var/www/page/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66
    PHP Fatal error:  composerRequire14063f7e5e06d46e1f9f9d444238e903(): Failed opening required '/App/Helpers/AppHelper.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/page/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66

    Fatal error: composerRequire14063f7e5e06d46e1f9f9d444238e903(): Failed opening required '/App/Helpers/AppHelper.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/page/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66
```

But when I do it on my windows machine its working fine.

The files Im trying to include are

```
    "files": [
        "App/Helpers/AppHelper.php",
        "App/Helpers/CoinHiveApi.php",
        "App/Helpers/CloudflareAPI.php"
    ]
```

Is there anyting I have to add/change?

Comment: Make sure that all files and folders are in the correct case. Windows doesn't care about casing when including files but linux does. They have to be exact. Linux treats `Somefile` and `somefile` as two different files/folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In laravel, You need to gives proper path(without any letter cases change) of file /Directive.

When you are work with composer.json, .env, any provider etc you need to run below command because laravel create cache itself.

1) composer update (If you add new package)

2) composer dump-autoload ([Why do I have to run "composer dump-autoload" command to make migrations work in laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33973967/why-do-i-have-to-run-composer-dump-autoload-command-to-make-migrations-work-in))

3) php artisan cache:clear

4) php artisan view:clear(if you add new view)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, case matters.

Composer takes file paths:

```
"files": [
    "app/Helpers/AppHelper.php",
    ...
]
```

`App !== app`

The folder is `app`.