# Receiving post-autodump-load error when pushing to Heroku

Tags: php, laravel, heroku, composer-php, laravel-5.7

I am running into the following errors when trying to push to `Heroku` using `git push heroku master`.

I thought I had updated everything, but nothing seems to be working.I have also compared to a recent application that I was able to push successfully.

I've included my `composer.json` file.

Laravel 5.7, Composer 1.6.3, PHP 7.2.11, Heroku 7.16.6, NodeJS 8.12.0

```
Generating optimized autoload files
remote:        > Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
remote:        > @php artisan package:discover --ansi
remote:        PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface' not found in /tmp/build_56561a046a1c53de95b0db0323d95d19/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php on line 25
remote:        Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 255
remote:  !     WARNING: A post-autoload-dump script terminated with an error
remote: 
remote:  !     ERROR: Dependency installation failed!
remote:  !     
remote:  !     The 'composer install' process failed with an error. The cause
remote:  !     may be the download or installation of packages, or a pre- or
remote:  !     post-install hook (e.g. a 'post-install-cmd' item in 'scripts')
remote:  !     in your 'composer.json'.
remote:  !     
remote:  !     Typical error cases are out-of-date or missing parts of code,
remote:  !     timeouts when making external connections, or memory limits.
Check the above error output closely to determine the cause of
remote:  !     the problem, ensure the code you're pushing is functioning
remote:  !     properly, and that all local changes are committed correctly.
remote:  !     
remote:  !     For more information on builds for PHP on Heroku, refer to
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support
remote:  !     
remote:  !     REMINDER: the following warnings were emitted during the build;
remote:  !     check the details above, as they may be related to this error:
remote:  !     - A post-autoload-dump script terminated with an error
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile PHP app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed

    > {
    >     "name": "laravel/laravel",
    >     "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    >     "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    >     "license": "MIT",
    >     "type": "project",
    >     "require": {
    >         "php": "^7.1.3",
    >         "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
    >         "laravel/framework": "5.7.*",
    >         "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
    >         "laravelcollective/html": "^5.4.0"
    >     },
    >     "require-dev": {
    >         "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.0",
    >         "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
    >         "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
    >         "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
    >         "nunomaduro/collision": "^2.0",
    >         "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.0",
    >         "symfony/web-server-bundle": "^4.1"
    >     },
    >     "autoload": {
    >         "classmap": [
    >             "database/seeds",
    >             "database/factories"
    >         ],
    >         "psr-4": {
    >             "App\\": "app/"
    >         }
    >     },
    >     "autoload-dev": {
    >         "psr-4": {
    >             "Tests\\": "tests/"
    >         }
    >     },
    >     "extra": {
    >         "laravel": {
    >             "dont-discover": [
    >             ]
    >         }
    >     },
    >     "scripts": {
    >         "post-root-package-install": [
    >             "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    >         ],
    >         "post-create-project-cmd": [
    >             "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
    >         ],
    >         "post-autoload-dump": [
    >             "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
    >             "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
    >         ]
    >     },
    >     "config": {
    >         "preferred-install": "dist",
    >         "sort-packages": true,
    >         "optimize-autoloader": true
    >     },
    >     "minimum-stability": "dev",
    >     "prefer-stable": true }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50824063/composer-cant-find-file-on-linux see this. I also experience it today when on windows it's just working well. -_-

Comment: I am facing this same error on server. All is working fine on local..