# Laravel - Seeding isn't refreshing

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to seed into an **orders** migration file, however upon using the command: **php artisan migrate:refresh --seed**, the following error is being returned.

```
ReflectionException  : Class OrdersTableSeeder does not exist
```

Either I'm stupid or Laravel is broken.

**Seeder:**

```
class OrdersTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('orders')->insert([
            'user_id' => 1,
            'product_id' => 1,
            'quantity' => 10,
            'updated_at' => DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')
        ]);

        DB::table('orders')->insert([
            'user_id' => 1,
            'product_id' => 2,
            'quantity' => 5,
            'updated_at' => DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')
        ]);
    }
}
```

**Migration:**

```
Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->integer('user_id'); //fk
    $table->integer('product_id'); //fk
    $table->integer('quantity');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Comment: Also, yes i've included it in my database seeder.

Comment: Do you have the correct import in your seeder: `use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;`. Try running `composer dump-autoload` just in case.

Comment: Every time you change/add something inside the database/seeds folder you need to `composer dump-autoload`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Class doesn't exists** error seems that Laravel couldn't find the class named **OrdersTableSeeder**.

I hope that using the below command helps.

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Explanation:

[Why do I have to run "composer dump-autoload" command to make migrations work in laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33973967/10086603)